# react-big-calendar, adding custom css class to event cells if there are more than two events in a date cell

Tags: css, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I'm using react calendar to display some events in a project. I want add a custom class to event cells; 'rbc-event' IF there are more than two of them in a single date cell; 'rbc-day-bg'.
Is it possible to do this? If so, how?